# ThreeJS - Scale texture's size down (no repeat - using UV-Coords)

Tags: three.js, textures, texture-mapping

Hello i am new to ThreeJS and texture mapping,

Let's say I have a 3D-Plane with the size of (1000x1000x1). When I apply a texture to it, it will be repeated or it will be scaled, to atleast filling the full plane.

What I try to achieve is, to change the scaling of the picture on the plane at runtime. I want the Image to get smaller and stop fitting the full plane.

I know there is a way to map each face to a part of a picture, but is it also possible to map it to a negative number in the picture, so it will be transparent?

My question is:

I UV-Mapped a Model in Blender and imported it with the UV-Coords into my ThreeJS-Code. Now i need to scale the texture down, like described before. Do I have to remap the UV-Cords or do i have to manipulate the image and add an transparent edge?

Further, will I be able on the same way to move the image on the picture?

I already achieved this kind of usage in java3d by manipulating bufferedImages and drawing them onto transparent ones. I am not sure this will be possible using javascript, so i want to know if it is possible by texture-mapping.

Thank you for your time and your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using mapping the 3d -plane to a canvas ,where the image is drawn (fabric.js can be used for canvas drawings).Inshort set the canvas as texture for the 3d model

`yourmodel.material.map = document.getElementById("yourCanvas");`

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In THREE, there are some controls on the texture object..

texture.repeat, and texture.offset .. they are both Vector2()s.

To repeat the texture twice you can do texture.repeat.set(2,2);

Now if you just want to scale but NOT repeat, there is also the "wrapping mode" for the texture.

texture.wrapS (U axis) and texture.wrapT (V axis) and these can be set to:

texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;

This will make the edge pixels of the texture extend off to infinity when sampling, so you can position a single small texture, anywhere on the surface of your uv mapped object.

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/textures/Texture

Between those two options (including texture.rotation) you can position/repeat a texture pretty flexibly.

If you need something even more complex.. like warping the texture or changing it's colors, you may want to change the UV's in your modeller, or draw your texture image into a canvas, modify the canvas, and use the canvas as your texture image, as described in ArUns answer. Then you can modify it at runtime as well.